# What should I do if an existing answer was wrong?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I'm disappointed several times that I answered a question after I found out one existing answer is **fundamentally** wrong (e.g. used the wrong language), so that not worth to edit at all. Then he/she/it corrected it after seeing my answer, and most *annoyingly*, my answer therefore get downvoted by later viewers!

What should I do?

I'm almost being tired on Stack Overflow trying to be helpful and get penalized at the same time!

Comment: Without seeing the Question/Answer we can't comment. Context is important here.

Comment: @CubeJockey my question was not really about that question. But it does suffer from comment deletion.

Comment: I intentionally avoid pointing the original question/answer(s) since I think it's a general question about "should I answer it if I found some other answer is wrong". I could delete this question if you all think it's context dependent.

Comment: @CubeJockey, Thank you. For your interest, I was forced to delete the answer to avoid further downvoting as I thought no one could actually judge as there's no such "comment history"

Comment: @zcui93 Can you at least provide us with the contents of those _misleading comments_ (from your memory) please?

Comment: If someone plagiarizes your answer then you can always mod flag.

Comment: @NathanOliver There's no indication of plagiarism, merely the statement that someone corrected the problem(s) with their answer in response to a comment pointing out the problem(s).

Comment: I could argue it's plagiarism since it's a simple Q&A.

Comment: Never mention in your answer that an other answer is incorrect. Do that separately in a comment to their answer. To further reduce the risk of downvotes you can phrase your comment "As it now stands, your answer is incorrect because...". That way people might be more prone to compare  the time stamp of your comment to the modification time of the answer before downvoting your answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can:

- Comment on the answer which is incorrect, explaining why it's incorrect
- Downvote the answer
- Create your own answer which you believe to be correct

You should ***not*** edit the answer to be correct.  Leave that to the answerer instead.

Outside of that, not much else.  Someone can *always* downvote your answer if they so feel like it, but you should do your best to ensure that your answer is correct and consistent.  If it is, others will see it and likely agree.

Comment: Ok then, so you did confirm that wrong answer should not copy the other's correct answer.

Comment: @zcui93:  If the incident happened within mere moments and it *seems* like it was a good-faith effort to correct errors, then there's no argument for plagiarism to be made.  However, flag for moderator attention if there's more concrete evidence of plagiarism to be had (as in, it was some hours after someone answered, and their answer was edited to be the same as that one).

Comment: @Makoto Out of interest, what should the original answerer do? Assume they've noticed the questioner doesn't seem to show any indication of wanting to change which one is accepted. Should they just delete it?

Comment: If you do answer, you could also **quote the incorrect answer**, linking to that point in the incorrect answers revision history. Then it's obvious to future readers why your answer was different.

Comment: @Shepmaster You don't have to quote: you do have to cite your source under the SO license.

Comment: @Yakk Shepmaster wasn't suggesting quoting to meet attribution requirements. It is to provide context to future readers, so they don't think the OP's later answer is a copy of the other user's updated answer.